# Conversion to Alloy 6

Tags: alloy

I'm running Alloy 6 (6.1.0) for the first time.  I've updated my syntax and am getting no error messages.  But checking assertions (that were valid in Alloy 5) I am fairly often getting:

0 vars. 0 primary vars.  507 ms.
No counterexample found.  Assertion may be valid.  0 ms.

This can't be right.  What should I do?

Comment: Hi Pamela! Can you share a minimal example that has the problem?

Comment: Today I can't reproduce the problem!  Well, that's good news—guess all is well unless it crops up again.

Comment: @Hovercouch:  It's back again!  Once, when Alloy 6 was freshly opened, the first execution of a check command worked and the second did not.  Now they all seem to be failing.  I am not familiar with stack overflow and don't know how to attach a file.  If you email me at pamela@pamelazave.com, I will send you the file.

Comment: That sounds like it might be a bug in Alloy itself. I'll email you, but you might also want to post to the discourse group.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was given by private mail. The issue is not specific to Alloy 6 as this behavior is already present in Alloy 5: Alloy is in fact able to solve some assertions even without calling a SAT solver, hence the `0` in `0 vars. 0 primary vars. 507 ms. No counterexample found. Assertion may be valid. 0 ms.`.